# how to make 2 inheriting classes share the same base class properties?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have a base class and 2 inheriting classes, and I need to use the base class properties
in different way in each of the inheriting classes. what would be the elegant way of implementing it?

I have a class basic that have maintains two different averages.
and the inheriting classes have a same method getAction(), and each one of them does a different calculation and base on the calculation it returns an action.
I want to have one instance of the averages for both of the inheriting classes.

Comment: An example of what you are trying to do would go a long way here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid inheritance if you can. The solution below is an implementation of the strategy pattern which should suit your needs perfectly.

```
class Params
{
    public int First {get;set;}
    public int Second {get;set;}
}

interface IAverageCounter
{
    double Calculate(Params parameters);
}

class SomeAverage : IAverageCounter
{
    public double Calculate(Params parameters)
    {
        return (parameters.First + parameters.Second) / 2;
    }
}


class OtherAverage : IAverageCounter
{
    public double Calculate(Params parameters)
    {
        return (parameters.Second - parameters.First) / 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would override the methods you need:

**[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)**

> Use the override modifier to modify a method, a property, an indexer,
>   or an event. An override method provides a new implementation of a
>   member inherited from a base class. The method overridden by an
>   override declaration is known as the overridden base method. The
>   overridden base method must have the same signature as the override
>   method.

```
   public class BaseClass
   {
      public double x;

      // Constructor:
      public Square(double x) 
      {
         this.x = x;
      }

      public virtual double Area() 
      {
         return x*x; 
      }
   }

   class InhertingClass1: BaseClass
   {
      // Constructor:
      public Cube(double x): base(x) 
      {
      }

      // Calling the Area base method:
      public override double Area() 
      {
         return (6*(base.Area())); 
      }
   }


   class InhertingClass2: BaseClass
   {
      // Constructor:
      public Cube(double x): base(x) 
      {
      }

      // Calling the Area base method:
      public override double Area() 
      {
         return (15*(base.Area())); 
      }
   }
```

Comment: Are the inheriting classes share the same X in this implemention?

Comment: In this example: yes! But you are also able to override this too

Comment: ok, just for knowledge if I am doing class1.cube(5) and class2.cube(5) there will be only one instance of base class? it wil not create base class instance for each of these inheriting classes?